# How to hide columns using HTML

Tags: java, html

Hello I have written one html code to hide/show columns. I have used "td:nth-child()" function by which i am toggling the column to hide & show. Here is the link for the code.

```
$(function() {  
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("td:nth-child(3)").toggle(); 
  });
});
```

I have 2 headers. One is main header & one is sub header of it. I am toggling 3rd column but sub headers of that column is not getting toggling & I want to toggle the complete columns including sub columns then how to do that?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzGCK/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess toggle is not colSpan aware. Maybe [this](http://blog.cynotwhynot.com/post/jQuery-ndash3b-Hiding-Table-Columns.aspx) helps or you will need to use a [plugin](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/columnmanager/) which is aware of colSpan

Comment: Hi Srikanth, Thanks for your reply. I tried with this but its not working..Is there any other way by which i can make it.
This is for my project. Please help me guys.
Thanks in advance.